# Swift: Inherit navigation bar class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a CustomNavBarController class that basically does everything related to my navigation bar. It adds all the buttons to my nav bar and takes care of all the functionalities.

As of now, I inherit this class like this:

```
class SomeController: CustomNavBarController
```

It works fine, but it currently blocks some of the things I want to do with my controllers, like adding collection views.

**CustomNavBarController.swift** (without the functions)

```
class CustomNavBarController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    func addButtonsToNavBar() {

        let homeButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        homeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        homeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedHome), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        homeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_home"), forState: .Normal)
        let homeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: homeButton)

        let messageButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        messageButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        messageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedMessage), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        messageButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_message"), forState: .Normal)
        let messageBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: messageButton)

        let userButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        userButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        userButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedProfile), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        userButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_user"), forState: .Normal)
        let userBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: userButton)

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [userBarButtonItem, messageBarButtonItem, homeBarButtonItem]
    }

    view.backgroundColor = Constants.MAIN_BACKGROUND_COLOR

    addButtonsToNavBar()
    }
}
```

**MainController.swift**

```
let cellId = "cellId"

class NewsController: UICollectionViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)

    collectionView?.registerClass(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 50)
    }
}

class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
}

// Load navigation bar items
class CustomNavBarController: NewsController {

}
```

In my MainController.swift file I am trying to load the nav bar items by subclassing it. Adding it to NewsController doesn't work anymore because of multiple inheritances.

In order to do this, should I change it to public first or is there a different method to accomplish this?

Comment: Multiple inheritance works with protocols so you could define a protocol and inherit at multiple instances. Another way would be to use extensions and define/add nav bar button items by extending UIViewController

Comment: All my controllers are UICollectionViewControllers, so that means that updating my nav bar class to an extension will not work?